# CORS no funciona en un API NET Core 5 con Auth

Tags: .net-core, cors, autenticación

Tengo un API en NET Core 5 con configuración para CORS y autenticación con Bearer JWT. La cuestión es que CORS no funciona.

Puedo realizar peticiones desde Postman y una aplicación Angular, corriendo en localhost:4200 sin problemas. No tengo idea porque CORS es omitido y mi único punto de seguridad es el JWT.

Como se observa en el controller.cs de ejemplo, cuando realizo la petición HTTP al método GetList del API, me solicitá el JWT, pero cuando realizo la petición HTTP al método Get es correcto que no requiere el JWT pero si debería entrar a funcionar CORS.

Setup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        /*
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         * Configuración del servicio de serialización de datos diferentes a JSON
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         */

        services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            // Definir en true si queremos que se retorne un código 406 Not Acceptable; cuando se solicite en la cabezera Accept, un formato no soportado
            // Definir en false si queremos que se retorne la información en el formato por omición y no se entregue un código 406 Not Acceptable
            options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;

            /*
             * Respeta la cabezera HTTP (Accept), donde el cliente espesifica el formato en el que requiere recibir la información por parte del controlador/web API.
             * Si el formato solicitado no es soportado, se retorna la información en el formato definido por omición por .Net Core, el cual es JSON.
             */
            options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;

            // Adiciona soporte al formato XML; como serialización de retorno de datos, por parte del controlador/web API
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
        })
        // Adiciona soporte para resolver propiedades en formato CamelCase, neceario para las operaciones PATCH
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        }).AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();

        /*
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         * Configuración de mensajes de error
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         */

        // Error 422: Error en el modelo de datos de entrada
        services.AddControllers().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
        {
            options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
            {
                ValidationProblemDetails validationProblemDetails = new(context.ModelState)
                {
                    Type = "",
                    Title = "One or more model validation errors ocurred.",
                    Status = StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity,
                    Detail = "See the errors property for details.",
                    Instance = context.HttpContext.Request.Path
                };

                validationProblemDetails.Extensions.Add("traceId", context.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier);

                return new UnprocessableEntityObjectResult(validationProblemDetails)
                {
                    ContentTypes = { "application/problem+json" }
                };
            };
        });

        /*
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         * Soporte a nuevos tipos de formatos JSON
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         */

        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter newtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter = options.OutputFormatters
                .OfType<NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter>()?.FirstOrDefault();

            if (!(newtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter is null))
            {
                // Retorna links del estandar HETEOAS
                newtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/hateoas+json");
            }

            XmlSerializerOutputFormatter xmlSerializerOutputFormatter = options.OutputFormatters
                .OfType<XmlSerializerOutputFormatter>()?.FirstOrDefault();

            if (!(xmlSerializerOutputFormatter is null))
            {
                // Retorna links del estandar HETEOAS
                xmlSerializerOutputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/hateoas+xml");
            }
        });

        /*
         * Mapeo de entidades a DTOs
         * La capa Infraestructure requiere el paquete Nuget: AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection (Nuget.org)
         * Agregar [using AutoMapper;] en este archivo
         */
        services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

        /*
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         * Configuración del contexto de la base de datos y la cadena de conexión
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         */

        // Establece el contexto de la base de datos y define la cadena de conexión establecida en el archivo appsettings.json
        services.AddDbContext<XXBaseDBContext>(options => {
            // ConnectionsString > ConnectionDatabase
            options.UseSqlServer(this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionDatabase"));
                // .UseLazyLoadingProxies(); Carga siempre las tablas relacionadas a la tabla de consulta principal
        });

        /*
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         * Configuración de los ámbitos de la aplicación
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         */

        /*
         * Repositorio
         */
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));

        /*
         *Contexto de la base de datos
         * Requiere del paquete Nuget: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (Nuget.org)
         */
        services.AddScoped(typeof(DbContext), typeof(XXBaseDBContext));

        /*
         * Servicios de la capa ApplicationCore
         * Requiere la dependencia con la capa Services
         */
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IBusinessLineService), typeof(BusinessLineService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(ICustomerService), typeof(CustomerService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(ICustomerUserService), typeof(CustomerUserService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IFileCategoryService), typeof(FileCategoryService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IFileLanguageService), typeof(FileLanguageService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IFileService), typeof(FileService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IFileTypeService), typeof(FileTypeService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IHttpRequest), typeof(PeoplesVoice.PS.Commons.HttpRequest.HttpRequest));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IIAMService), typeof(IAMService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IInternalUserService), typeof(InternalUserService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(ILanguageService), typeof(LanguageService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(ILicenseCustomerUserService), typeof(LicenseCustomerUserService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(ILicenseTypeService), typeof(LicenseTypeService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(ILicenseService), typeof(LicenseService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IProductFileService), typeof(ProductFileService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IProjectSectionDisabledService), typeof(ProjectSectionDisabledService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IProductSectionService), typeof(ProductSectionService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IProductService), typeof(ProductService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IProductStatusService), typeof(ProductStatusService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IProjectSubsectionDisabledService), typeof(ProjectSubsectionDisabledService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IProductSubsectionService), typeof(ProductSubsectionService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IProjectService), typeof(ProjectService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IProjectUserService), typeof(ProjectUserService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(ISentEmailService), typeof(SentEmailService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IServicePortalService), typeof(ServicePortalService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(ISetupService), typeof(SetupService));
        services.AddHttpClient();

        /*
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         * Configuración del versionamiento de las web APIs/Controladores
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         */

        /*
         * Versionamiento de una web API
         * Requiere del paquete Nuget: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning (Nuget.org)
         */
        services.AddApiVersioning(options => {
            // Cabezera HTTP, donde debe especificarse la versión del web API a usar
            HeaderApiVersionReader headerApiVersionReader = new("api-version");

            // Indica que en la petición señalamos qué versión de la API soporta la petición que hemos realizado.
            options.ReportApiVersions = true;

            // En caso de que no se notifique la versión en la petición, cómo tratamos dicha petición (si se envía un error o bien si asume la versión por defecto).
            options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            // Versión por defecto la API
            options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(2, 0);

            // Ubicación donde indicamos la versión, ya sea por QueryString o por HeaderAPIVersión
            options.ApiVersionReader = headerApiVersionReader;
        });

        /*
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         * Configuración del servicio de seguridad => CORS
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         */

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            // Cors para uso en entorno de desarrollo
            options.AddPolicy(name: "development", builder =>
            {
                // builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithExposedHeaders("Etag");
                builder.WithOrigins(Configuration["CorsOrigin"].Split(",")).AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials().WithExposedHeaders("Etag");
            });

            // Cors para uso en entorno de pruebas
            options.AddPolicy(name: "staging", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins(Configuration["CorsOrigin"].Split(",")).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithExposedHeaders("Etag");
            });

            // Cors para uso en entorno de producción
            options.AddPolicy(name: "production", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins(Configuration["CorsOrigin"].Split(",")).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithExposedHeaders("Etag");
            });
        });

        //OPEN-ID CONNECT BEARER TOKEN
        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddJwtBearer("XXAdminWebUI", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = Configuration["Authority"];
            options.Audience = Configuration["XXX:XXAdminWebUI:ClientId"];
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        });

        /*
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         * Configuración del servicio de cache HTTP
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         */

        // services.AddResponseCaching();
        
        services.AddHttpCacheHeaders((expirationModelOptions) =>
        {
            expirationModelOptions.MaxAge = 0;
            expirationModelOptions.CacheLocation = Marvin.Cache.Headers.CacheLocation.Private;
        },
        (validationModelOptions) =>
        {
            // Obliga a el sistema de Cache del cliente (exam: Navegadores), a que cuando una respuesta es obsoleta por el valor definido
            // en max-age, se deba validar con el servidor de origen, si existe una respuesta más reciente
            validationModelOptions.MustRevalidate = true;
        });

        /*
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         * Configuración del servicio de documentación y OpenAPI
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         */

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest));
            options.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound));
            options.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(StatusCodes.Status423Locked));
        });

        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.UseAllOfToExtendReferenceSchemas();
            options.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "XXAdminWebAPI", Version = "v2" });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsStaging())
        {
            // Define mostrar total detalle del error
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            // Usar swagger para visualizar la documentación en formato ApenAPI
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "XXAdminWebAPI v2"));
        }

        if (env.IsProduction())
        {
            // Definir mensaje de error cuando este sea un error inesperado del lado el servidor.
            app.UseExceptionHandler(erroApi =>
            {
                erroApi.Run(async context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("An unexpected failure occurred. Try again later.");
                });
            });
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        // Usa el CORS especificado
        app.UseCors(env.EnvironmentName.ToLower());
        // Se requiere agregar ahora esta opción al middleware con aspnetcore 3.0+
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        // app.UseResponseCaching();
        app.UseHttpCacheHeaders();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
        app.UseApiVersioning();
    }
}
```

Controller.cs (Ejemplo)

```
// Control de versiones soportadas por el endpoint de este controlador
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
// Control de versiones no soportadas por el endpoint de este controlador
[ApiVersion("1.0", Deprecated = true)]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "XXAdminWebUI", Roles = "xx-master, xx-project-manager")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetList()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public WeatherForecast Get(int id)
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Today,
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        };
    }
}
```

En el appsettings.json y appsettings.Development.json tengo la siguiente configuración

```
"CorsOrigin": "https://www.xx-xxadminwebui.azurewebsites.net,https://xx-xxadminwebui.azurewebsites.net,https://www.yy-yyadminwebui.azurewebsites.net,https://yy-yyadminwebui.azurewebsites.net,https://www.zz.xyz.com,https://zz.xyz.com",...
```

Comment: 2 cosas: 1. `No tengo idea porque CORS es omitido` ¿Has intentado mover `app.UseCors(env.EnvironmentName.ToLower());` antes del Routing y HttpsRedirection? 2. ¿Cuál es el error que te muestra?

Comment: igual, corrigeme si me equivoco @fredyfx, pero cors no tiene absolutamente nada que ver con el metodo de autenticacion....

Comment: @gbianchi Sí y no, sucede que el orden es importante; en la configuración de servicios puede dar lo mismo cómo defines qué cosa, en el cómo le das el uso sí genera error en el orden de los middlewares.

Comment: @gbianchi Solo como extra, actualmente yo trabajo en unas APIs que requieren autenticación, y esta si no son enviadas, nos tira problemas de CORS... Puede que hay sido algo por el estilo

Comment: Logre resolverlo. Resuelta que el problema no era la configuración en el Setup.cs sino la forma como realizaba la prueba. Si se realiza la petición desde Postman, el origen será el mismo del API, por lo que siempre superará CORS. Cree un archivo HTML con un pequeño script de JS y realice la misma petición; esa prueba si me permitió evidenciar los diferentes escenarios entre CORS y Auth.

Answer (score 0):

eso sucede porque estas llamando tus sitios del `appsettings.json` y despues haces un split, eso lo convierte en un arreglo, tendrias que hacer foreach y recorrer cada dominio, pero es mejor agregar manualmente desde [WithOrigins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

```
 options.AddPolicy(name: "development", builder =>
{
// builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithExposedHeaders("Etag");
builder.WithOrigins("https://www.xx-xxadminwebui.azurewebsites.net","https://xx-xxadminwebui.azurewebsites.net","https://www.yy-yyadminwebui.azurewebsites.net","https://yy-yyadminwebui.azurewebsites.net","https://www.zz.xyz.com,https://zz.xyz.com").AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials().WithExposedHeaders("Etag");
});
```

tambien puedes probar entrar directamente con el arreglo, que en este caso seria el primer primer sitio al hacer el split `https://www.xx-xxadminwebui.azurewebsites.net`

```
builder.WithOrigins(Configuration["CorsOrigin"].Split(",")[0])

options.AddPolicy(name: "development", builder =>
            {
                // builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithExposedHeaders("Etag");
                builder.WithOrigins(Configuration["CorsOrigin"].Split(",")[0]).AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials().WithExposedHeaders("Etag");
            });
```

Edit*
otra manera de hacerlo, es de esta manera, como muestra en este [post](https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/enable-cors-net-core-73ba24ea5f2a)

```
"CorsOrigin": ["https://www.xx-xxadminwebui.azurewebsites.net","https://xx-xxadminwebui.azurewebsites.net"]

options.AddPolicy(name: "staging", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins(Configuration.GetSection["CorsOrigin"].Get<string[]>()).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithExposedHeaders("Etag");
            });
```

Comment: Hola @Daniel, realice la configuración como dices pero sigue sin funcionar; de hecho, cree un proyecto nuevo de Net Core 5 Web API y el Cors tampoco me funciono.

Comment: @DavidAndrésGómezZamora y modificaste tu `appsettings` y que error te da?

Comment: y en configuration, creo que deberias agregar todos tus cors, porque solo veo que tienes `app.UseCors(env.EnvironmentName.ToLower());`, cuanto en realidad tienes 3, `app.UseCors("development");` , `app.UseCors("staging");` , `app.UseCors("production");` ,

Comment: No genera ningún error y como te comentaba, incluso en un nuevo proyecto sin Auth, Cors sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: @DavidAndrésGómezZamora deberia darte un error de cors, porque ese es tu pregunta, debes ver en tu navegador o en donde estas consumiendo el servicio, debe darte el error de cors, y el sitio que esta bloqueando, o debuggea en tu end point de tu controlador, para que veas si esta entrando y poco a poco miras que error te arrojara o te da el resultado esperado

Comment: Logre resolverlo. Resuelta que el problema no era la configuración en el Setup.cs sino la forma como realizaba la prueba. Si se realiza la petición desde Postman, el origen será el mismo del API, por lo que siempre superará CORS. Cree un archivo HTML con un pequeño script de JS y realice la misma petición; esa prueba si me permitió evidenciar los diferentes escenarios entre CORS y Auth.